# How to open cURL in Firefox or other web browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, curl, firebug

I have Firebug installed in Firefox. In the *Net* panel there are all network requests listed. When I right-click and choose *Copy as cURL*, how do I use this cURL?

How can I repeat my POST request data using cURL?

The copied cURL looks like this:

```
curl 'http://www.softwareishard.com/firebug/tips/resend/hello.php' -H 'Host: www.softwareishard.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -H 'Referer: http://www.softwareishard.com/firebug/tips/resend/resend.html' --data 'name=Bob'
```

Comment: What is your OS? *nix? copy/paste into your shell. Windows? You can recreate in Fiddler. Other? Just hit replay it in Firebug.

Comment: [How To Bypass CORS Errors On Chrome And Firefox For Testing](http://pointdeveloper.com/how-to-bypass-cors-errors-on-chrome-and-firefox-for-testing/) if CORS is issue.  Otherwise CORS equivalent is traditionally built in XHR, new way appears to be fetch api.

Answer (score 0):

cURL is not part of Firefox or Firebug, i.e. it cannot be executed there. As the [Firebug wiki explains](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel#Copying_a_request_as_a_cURL_command):

> cURL is a command line tool for transferring data with URL syntax. Firebug's *Copy As cURL* command recreates the HTTP request (including HTTP headers and query string parameters) and copies it as a cURL command string to the clipboard.
>   The string can be pasted into a terminal window to execute the same request or for example pasted to a client that supports cURL.
>   In cases where the server serves compressed responses the preference `extensions.firebug.net.curlAddCompressedArgument` can be set to `true` and Firebug will add the `--compressed argument` to the generated command string.

It also refers to the [cURL homepage](http://curl.haxx.se/).

What Firebug offers is to resend the right-clicked request via the *Resend* option within the context menu.